# Node.js, PostgreSQL error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, heroku

I am following this article ((http://nodeexamples.com/2012/09/21/connecting-to-a-postgresql-database-from-node-js-using-the-pg-module/). I have already deployed my app to heroku and currently using express, node.js, to try and connect to a PostgresSQL database in Heroku that I just installed. I get to the very end of the article and I use the command

```
node myfile.js
```

I get this error

```
error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "...", user "...", database "...", ...
```

How do I go about creating one and where in my app directory should I put it?

Below is the entire error message. I changed the strings for IP address, user, and database but it looks basically just like it.

```
events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "00.000.000.00", user "username", database "databasename", SSL off
at Connection.parseE (/Users/user/workspace/MyApp/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:526:11)
at Connection.parseMessage (/Users/user/workspace/MyApp/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:356:17)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/user/workspace/MyApp/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:105:22)
at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
at Socket.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:748:14)
at Socket.emit (events.js:92:17)
at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:410:10)
at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:406:5)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:168:9)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:130:10)
```

---

Edit: I did some more research and found that the 'pg_hba.conf' file is in my

```
/usr/local/var/postgres
```

and I added this line into the 'pg_hba.conf' file

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
 host   all             all                                     trust
```

also tried

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
host   all             all              0.0.0.0/0               md5
```

but it keeps saying there is no entry for my host, user, database, etc...
is my 'pg_hba.conf' syntax wrong in any way?

Comment: [pg_hba.conf](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html)

Comment: you'll want to edit /etc/postgresql/X.Y/main/pg_hba.conf. you'll need to add a line that looks like: "host mydatabase myuser 0.0.0.0/0 md5". @Rhim provided you a link with full documentation on that file so you should refer to that first.

Comment: @aembke Thank you for your answer. Where is the /etc/ directory?

Comment: it's in the root directory, assuming you're running on linux.

Comment: Oh, are you saying you deployed this to heroku and you saw this error? or you tried to run this on your own box? If you're doing this on heroku you'll likely need to first provision your database. First you should walk through this guide: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#provisioning-the-add-on. Then you'll need to modify your code to connect using heroku's environment variables: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#connecting-in-node-js. They should take care of the pg_hba.conf modifications for you if you follow their guides.

Comment: @aembke I have already deployed this to heroku and now trying to connect to heroku's PostgreSQL database. I'll definitely check out those links and let you know how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: Regarding the second link though, doesn't the work that I already did following the article I've attached above take care of connecting already?

Comment: Also when I call 'heroku addons | grep POSTGRES' as stated in the first link I already have a database connected 'heroku-postgresql:dev  HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_MYDB' I just want to add the 'pg_hba.conf' file

Comment: can you post the entire error? not the credentials, but the entire error string verbatim.

Comment: ^^I've just updated the question

Comment: try changing that bottom line to: "host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5"

Comment: Still the same issue, no change

Comment: I also faced this issue when using Heroku Postgres offering. For latest answer, see the latest comments on issue https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/278

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Change your connection code to use ssl. Following your linked example:

```
var conString = "pg://admin:guest@localhost:5432/Employees";
var client = new pg.Client(conString);
client.connect();
```

becomes:

```
var client = new pg.Client({
    user: "admin",
    password: "guest",
    database: "Employees",
    port: 5432,
    host: "localhost",
    ssl: true
}); 
client.connect();
```

https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/wiki/Client#new-clientobject-config--client

Comment: that's an error with your application code. i'd open a new question on that issue, it's not at all related to the original question. you should post all of you application code in the new question too.

Answer (score 51):

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize({
  database: "DB",
  username: "root",
  password: "pass",
  host: "localhost",
  port: 5432,
  dialect: "postgres",
  dialectOptions: {
    ssl: {
      require: true, // This will help you. But you will see nwe error
      rejectUnauthorized: false // This line will fix new error
    }
  },
});
```

Comment: This is the correct solution as of `pg` version `8.5.1`.
https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/278

Comment: You saved my day Victor!

Comment: This solution has worked for me, with Sequelize ORM. You saved me.

Comment: This worked for me! Thank you! Love the comments explaining why each option is required

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked for me after spending hours

Comment: Spending the whole day you saved my time bro. Thanks

Answer (score 32):

**Running on heroku:**

We ran into this error while upgrading the pg database on heroku from `hobby` tier to `standard-0`. SSL is required, but we didnt set it in our config.

Include in config when initialize new Sequelize(...)

```
"dialect": "postgres",
"dialectOptions": {
  "ssl": true
}
```

This trick was, that the ssl option is wrapped in `dialectOptions`.
found here: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/956#issuecomment-147745033

Info by @Atish:
Use

```
options: { 
  dialect: "postgres",
  native: true, # adding this maybe breaks on hobby dyno
  ssl: true, 
  dialectOptions: {
    ssl: true
  }
}
```

Comment: Use 
`options: { dialect:'postgres', native:true, ssl:true, dialectOptions: {ssl: true}'`

Comment: My experience, using Hobby tier Heroku pg:  the app sequelize connection works without `native:true`, and adding this option breaks it. Sequelize CLI not working in either scenario as yet.

Comment: @defraggled I have added your hint about the hobby dyno

Answer (score 19):

In the case sequelize ignores all of your efforts to turn ssl on, you can try to convince pg to enable ssl for all conncetions by default:

```
var pg = require('pg');
pg.defaults.ssl = true;

const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = new Sequelize('postgres://...');
```

Comment: Another option, slightly cleaner imo, is to do following in your `sequelizeConfig`:

`{ "dialect":"postgres", "ssl":true, "dialectOptions":{ "ssl": {"require":true } }}`

https://github.com/sequelize/cli/issues/154#issuecomment-167960024

Comment: In my case this worked, but revealed a further error as described and resolved by this q/a: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61350416/9466397

Answer (score 14):

Adding `?ssl=true` should work to the end of the uri.

```
var conString = "pg://admin:guest@localhost:5432/Employees?ssl=true";
```

Comment: Append `?sslmode=require` instead of `?ssl=true` Here are 2 references that talks about it 1) https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#heroku-postgres-ssl 2) https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/libpq-ssl.html

Answer (score 12):

You can also use the ENVIRONMENT CONFIG VARIABLE 'PGSSLMODE' to 'require' via Heroku's web interface or CLI.

Case: Postgres dB set up as a Heroku add-on and attached to app on a Heroku Dyno.

Heroku provides some pretty good support on how to connect to one of its add-on databases; however, it unfortunately leaves out (or, I missed it) any mention of what do to enforce SSL since all Heroku dB tiers starting with Standard-0 enforces SSL by default.

Comment: Thanks - had upgraded to Standard-0 and didn't see a warning that this would change SSL requirements, that caused a mild scare.

Comment: Heroku recently send a warning saying it was going to force SSL. They included similar documentation to what was posted above. I followed those instructions and my app just crashed today, because of SSL issues. I added the PGSSLMODE config variable and everything is back to normal. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

DialectOptions with SSL works, but you can also update the config var PGSSLMODE.

> Alternatively, you can omit the ssl configuration object if you
> specify the PGSSLMODE config var: heroku config:set
> PGSSLMODE=no-verify.

See [Heroku guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#connecting-in-node-js)

Heroku announced this SSL change on their changelog [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/2035)

Answer (score 6):

While creating the pg client, this config fixed the issue for me. You can also read the detail doc written on the module's website here >>> https://node-postgres.com/features/ssl. Thank you.

```
new pg.client({
  connectionString,
  ssl: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
  },
})
```

Comment: great idea. I try it in the knex configuration file for the deploy branch but it didn't work.

Answer (score 5):

What worked for me was a combination of above answers and a comment(from @schybo)

```
let cloud_config = {
  username: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
  database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  host: process.env.DB_HOSTNAME,
  port: 5432,
  ssl: true,
  dialect: 'postgres',
  dialectOptions: {
    "ssl": {"require":true }
  }
};
```

Use both `ssl: true,` and `dialectOptions: { "ssl": {"require":true }}`

[Comment](https://github.com/sequelize/cli/issues/154#issuecomment-167960024) on Sequelize issue which is also added to the docs.

Comment: For me just needed `dialectOptions`

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue again and again.
The packages:

```
"pg": "^8.5.1",
"pg-hstore": "^2.3.3",
"sequelize": "^6.5.0",
"sequelize-cli": "^6.2.0"
```

I solved it by adding the following in the config.json file in the Sequelize.

```
"dialect": "postgres",
"dialectOptions": {
  "ssl": {
    "rejectUnauthorized": false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
const Pool = require("pg").Pool;

const proConfig = {
  connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  ssl: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  }
}

const pool = new Pool(proConfig);

module.exports = pool;
```

Answer (score 3):

Because node-Postgres enables SSL validation by default while free Heroku hosting doesn’t provide it automatically, you need to turn it off.
disable SSL in Heroku:

```
heroku config:set PGSSLMODE=no-verify --app <app name>
```

https://dpletzke.medium.com/configuring-free-heroku-node-postgresql-hosting-with-knex-b0e97a05c6af

https://help.heroku.com/DR0TTWWD/seeing-fatal-no-pg_hba-conf-entry-errors-in-postgres

Answer (score 2):

If you are deploying Sails.js on Heroku, add the following to your database configuration:

```js
ssl: {
  sslmode: 'require',
  rejectUnauthorized: false,
}
```

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66913689/1320621

Comment: Just wanted to know if there is any implication or security risk involved by adding the above snippet? @Kaspi

Answer (score 0):

Just add a flag to the client initialisation:

Change

```
const conString = "pg://admin:guest@localhost:5432/Employees"
const client = new pg.Client(conString);
client.connect();
```

To

```
const conString = "pg://admin:guest@localhost:5432/Employees"
const client = new pg.Client({
  connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  ssl: true
});
client.connect();
```

Answer (score 0):

setting `ssl: true` worked for me

```
let pg = require('pg');

let pgClient = new pg.Client({
    user: "admin",
    password: "guest",
    database: "Employees",
    port: 5432,
    host: "localhost",
    ssl: true
}); 
pgClient.connect();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add

```
ssl: true
```

in json connection

```
    {
        host: 'myHost.com',
        user: 'myUser',     
        password: 'myPassword',
        database: 'myDb',
        port: 5432,
        ssl: true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

just update your database/config.js file by allowing and requiring SSL

```
  production: {
    use_env_variable: 'DATABASE_URL',
    dialect: 'postgresql',
    ssl: true,
    dialectOptions: {
      ssl: { require: true },
    },
    logging: false,
  },
```

after this might run into another issue: nodejs - error self-signed certificate in
If that's the case, add `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED='0'` as an environment variable wherever you are running node or running node directly with `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED='0'` node app.js

Answer (score 0):

Mine was none of these solutions even though the error was the same, after trying all the above solutions for days to no avail I later figured out I added a semicolon (;) to the end of my connection string as in below;

```js
DB_URL=pg://admin:guest@localhost:5432/Employees;

//instead of

DB_URL=pg://admin:guest@localhost:5432/Employees
```

the semicolon technically had added an extra character that isn't part of the configuration/authentication document hence wasn't recognized. A silly and avoidable mistake that can be made by anyone. Pay attention to details