# Postgrex - No pg_hba.conf entry for host "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"

Tags: postgresql, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have a Postgres Database hosted separately which I'm trying to use with my Phoenix Application. My `prod` config is:

```
config :my_app, MyApp.Repo,
  adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres,
  url: "postgres://username:password@myhost:5432/my_database",
  size: 20
```

This worked fine while my application was hosted on Heroku, but since I've moved it to a VPS, I keep getting this error:

```
17:07:13.665 [info] GET /subjects
17:07:13.707 [info] Processing by MyApp.SubjectController.index/2
  Parameters: %{"format" => "html"}
  Pipelines: [:browser, :authorize]
17:07:13.951 [error] GenServer #PID<0.515.0> terminating
** (exit) %Postgrex.Error{message: nil, postgres: %{code: :invalid_authorization_specification, file: "auth.c", line: "474", message: "no pg_hba.conf entry for host \"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\", user \"username\", database \"my_database\", SSL off", pg_code: "28000", routine: "ClientAuthentication", severity: "FATAL"}}
17:07:13.970 [info] Sent 500 in 305ms
17:07:13.972 [error] #PID<0.513.0> running MyApp.Endpoint terminated
Server: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80 (http)
Request: GET /subjects
** (exit) exited in: GenServer.call(#PID<0.515.0>, {:query, "SELECT s0.\"id\", s0.\"name\", s0.\"inserted_at\", s0.\"updated_at\" FROM \"subjects\" AS s0", []}, 5000)
    ** (EXIT) %Postgrex.Error{message: nil, postgres: %{code: :invalid_authorization_specification, file: "auth.c", line: "474", message: "no pg_hba.conf entry for host \"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\", user \"username\", database \"my_database\", SSL off", pg_code: "28000", routine: "ClientAuthentication", severity: "FATAL"}}
```

I can also connect to the Database from Postgres GUI tools, so there isn't anything wrong with that. One thing that I noted was that it states my VPS IP as the host instead of the host specified in the url.

It shouldn't matter since the Database is on a separate host altogether, but I still tried the solutions here:

- [No pg_hba.conf entry for host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406025/no-pg-hba-conf-entry-for-host)
- [Connect to PostgreSQL server: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83984/connect-to-postgresql-server-fatal-no-pg-hba-conf-entry-for-host)

Really struggling with this, please help!

**Update: Here's my `pg_hba.conf`:**

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                peer
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
```

Comment: pg_hba.conf is a file which lists where you can connect to the database **from**, so it should be no surprise that it doesn't mention the hostname you tried to connect **to**.

Comment: Also, what specifically did you try? Maybe [edit] the question to include your current pg_hba.conf.

Comment: Updated. I added the last line to allow access to all addresses from all.

Comment: Please delete this question since it is a simple configuration issue.

Comment: Why? This could still help other developers. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is so stupid, but I figured out the problem. The host I was trying to connect to, expected a secure database connection. By default, SSL is turned off, so I had enable it:

```
config :my_app, MyApp.Repo,
  adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres,
  url: "postgres://username:password@myhost:5432/my_database",
  ssl: true,
  size: 20
```

---

*Thanks to this answer: [Node.js, PostgreSQL error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25004023/1533054)*