# React-Heroku Postgress-Addon: GET http://app-name.herokuapp.com/any 503 (Service Unavailable)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, postgresql, express

I'm trying to deploy a CRUD todo-list app to Heroku. I'm using React, NodeJS and the Postgress Addon from heroku. I dind't get any error during deployment, however it seems the front-end is not connected with the back-end. When I try to add a new "todo" I get the next message (also the app fails to fetch entries from the DB):

[image: Console]

[image: report from: heroku logs]

[image: Info postgres-Addon Heroku DB]

**index.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const pool = require("./db");
const path = require("path");
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

//middleware
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json()); // => allows us to access the req.body


if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  //server static content
  //npm run build
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client/build")));
}

console.log(__dirname);
console.log(path.join(__dirname, "client/build"));

//ROUTES//
//get all Todos
app.get("/todos", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const allTodos = await pool.query("SELECT * FROM todo");

    res.json(allTodos.rows);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  }
});

//get a todo
app.get("/todos/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const todo = await pool.query("SELECT * FROM todo WHERE todo_id = $1", [
      id,
    ]);
    res.json(todo.rows[0]);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  }
});

//create a todo
app.post("/todos", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log(req.body);
    const { description } = req.body;
    const newTodo = await pool.query(
      "INSERT INTO todo (description) VALUES ($1) RETURNING *",
      [description]
    );

    res.json(newTodo.rows[0]);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  }
});

//update a todo
app.put("/todos/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const { description } = req.body;
    const updateTodo = await pool.query(
      "UPDATE todo SET description = $1 WHERE todo_id = $2",
      [description, id]
    );

    res.json("Todo was updated");
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  }
});

//delete a todo
app.delete("/todos/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const deleteTodo = await pool.query("DELETE FROM todo WHERE todo_id = $1", [
      id,
    ]);
    res.json("Todo was deleted");
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  }
});

app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "client/build/index.html"));
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is starting on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

**db.js**

```
const Pool = require("pg").Pool;
require("dotenv").config();

const devConfig = `postgresql://${process.env.PG_USER}:${process.env.PG_PASSWORD}@${process.env.PG_HOST}:${process.env.PG_PORT}/${process.env.PG_DATABASE}`;

const proConfig = process.env.DATABASE_URL; //heroku addons

const pool = new Pool({
  connectionString:
    process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? proConfig : devConfig,
});

module.exports = pool;
```

**package.json (root dir)**

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.14.2",
    "npm": "6.14.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install && npm run build"
  },
  "author": "henry",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "pg": "^7.18.2"
  }
}
```

**package.json(client)**

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
}
```

I am using the code from the following git-repository: https://github.com/l0609890/pern-deploy-tutorial.
And following the next instructions (I think you can skip the video to min 34:00): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZJxUOOND5_A

THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: `2021-02-18T06:34:45.692018+00:00 app[web.1]: { description: 'hi' }
2021-02-18T06:34:45.927723+00:00 app[web.1]: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "35.175.243.252", user "arkqcuvolsgwnz", database "d2l3k93rvhp242", SSL off
2021-02-18T06:34:51.137702+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/todos" host=todo-app-pern-stack.herokuapp.com request_id=caf16648-4ee5-444a-85f1-f845c183885e fwd="104.185.38.51" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https`

Answer (score 0):

Since Heroku is using load balancer managed by Heroku the timeout is set to 30secs.

if there is an error the in the catch block your seem to haven't returned the function with an error response.

please send a response in the catch block to terminate the function and to avoid timeout errors

**Suggestion**:

return respone with the appropriate status code with respective error message

Answer (score 0):

I was following that tutorial too. It turns out you just need to add `ssl` property to your `proConfig`

```
const proConfig = {
  connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  ssl: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  }
};
```

Source: [Node.js, PostgreSQL error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25000183/node-js-postgresql-error-no-pg-hba-conf-entry-for-host)