# Unable to connect nodejs app to Postrgres database on heroku using typeorm

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku, typeorm

I am using typeorm to connect to Postgres database on my nodejs application. I am able to connect successfully on my local but upon deploying to heroku I have these errors based on my database configurations.

```js
import { createConnection } from 'typeorm';
...

export const databaseConnection = async (databaseURL:string) => {
    try {
        await createConnection({
            type: "postgres",
            url: databaseURL,
            entities: [User],
            synchronize: true,
            ssl:  false
        });
        

    } catch (error) {
    }
};

databaseConnection("<DATABASE_URL_FROM_HEROKU>")
```

When I do this, I get the error `no pg_hba.conf entry for host , userdatabase  SSL off at Parser.parseErrorMessage`

And when I use `ssl: true` in the connection I get the error: `Error: self signed certificate at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure heroku`

When I removed the ssl property completely, it still didn't work.

Most of the solutions I came across were done using sequelize like this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25000183/node-js-postgresql-error-no-pg-hba-conf-entry-for-host).  but I am using typeorm. I do I get rid of this error please.

Answer (score 0):

Did you to try like this :

```
await createConnection({
  type: "postgres",
  url: databaseURL,
  entities: [User],
  synchronize: true,
  ssl: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  }
});
```

Comment: It throws the error: `Error: The server does not support SSL connections
    at Socket.`