# NodeJs postgresql connection failure

Tags: node.js, postgresql, amazon-rds, pg

- I try to connect to rds postgresql **version 12** from nodeJs as mentioned below. It works completely fine without any issue.

  ```
  const config = {

      user: process.env.PG_DB_USERNAME,
      password: process.env.PG_DB_PASSWORD,
      database: process.env.PG_DB_NAME,
      host: process.env.PG_DB_HOST,
      port: process.env.PG_DB_PORT,
   }
     const pool = new Pool(config)
  ```

When we use postgresql **version 15.2**  ton connect from node Js  we ended up facing the below error.

**Error**

`{"length":181,"name":"error","severity":"FATAL","code":"28000","file":"auth.c","line":"543","routine":"ClientAuthentication","level":"error","timestamp":"2023-06-19T14:13:33.294Z"}`

```
[ERROR] error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "XXXXX", user "test", database "testdb", no encryption

at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/usr/src/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:287:98)
at Parser.handlePacket (/usr/src/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:126:29)
at Parser.parse (/usr/src/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:39:38)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:11:42)
at Socket.emit (node:events:526:28)
at Socket.emit (node:domain:475:12)
at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23)
at TCP.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17)
```

I tried passing the below params as suggested in various stack overflow links, but ended with same error.

We tried deploying the code as suggested in the below link , but it's not resolved.

Reference: [Node.js, PostgreSQL error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25000183/node-js-postgresql-error-no-pg-hba-conf-entry-for-host)

`"dialectOptions": { "ssl": true }`

`ssl: true`

Could you please help in fixing this error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is , before version 15, postgresql has the default paramater value ( db parameter group ) for force_ssl as 0.

Starting from version 15 they made this default value to 1.

Setting it to 0 resolved this Issue.

From aws doc,

> You can require that connections to your PostgreSQL DB instance use
> SSL by using the rds.force_ssl parameter. The default rds.force_ssl
> parameter is set to 1 (on) for RDS for PostgreSQL version 15. All
> other RDS for PostgreSQL major version 14 and older have the default
> value for rds.force_ssl parameter set to 0 (off). You can set the
> rds.force_ssl parameter to 1 (on) to require SSL for connections to
> your DB instance.

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/PostgreSQL.Concepts.General.SSL.html

Comment: any idea how to turn this off using cloud formation? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-rds-dbinstance.html

Comment: Thank you very useful. Experienced this issue upgrading from Postgres v14 to v15.
Simply connect using SSL and it should work.